# Offline event registration Pay later option

Tags: civievent, registration

I want to be able to offline register user, that will pay later.
If in 'Payment information' I set an amount of 0 and a 'Payment status' to 'pending', 'Participant Status' is always set to 'Partially paid' and not the status that I have set, when an confirmation and receipt is send by email.
If 'Send Confirmation and Receipt' is unchecked, 'Participant Status' is not changed, and only contribution status is set to Pending (Pay Later)

It should be nice to have a 'Pay later' checkbox so it's not mandatory to record an empty payment.

Is it possible?

Thank you for your help,

Olivier.

Comment: any reason you can't do the above by going to a contribution form and have cid=0 or use the 'register as another person', ie use the public form but put in their details and set as 'pay later' via the form

Comment: ah yes it's true, i hadn't thought of this solution.
Thank you.

Comment: cool. i added as an answer. if it was helpful then pls +1 and Accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the above by going to a contribution form and have cid=0 or use the 'register as another person', ie use the public form but put in their details and set as 'pay later' via the form